# Pytorch Problem: My jupyter stuck when num_workers > 0

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

This is a snippet of my code in PyTorch, my jupiter notebook stuck when I used num_workers > 0, I spent a lot on this problem without any answer. I do not have a GPU and I work only with a CPU.

```
class IndexedDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self,data,targets, test=False):
    self.dataset = data 
    if not test:
        self.labels = targets.numpy()
        self.mask =  np.concatenate((np.zeros(NUM_LABELED), np.ones(NUM_UNLABELED)))


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = self.dataset[idx]
        return image, self.labels[idx]
    
    def display(self, idx):
        plt.imshow(self.dataset[idx], cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

train_set = IndexedDataset(train_data, train_target, test = False)

test_set = IndexedDataset(test_data, test_target, test = True)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=2)

test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=2)
```

Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `num_workers` is greater than 0, PyTorch uses multiple processes for data loading.

Jupyter notebooks have known issues with multiprocessing.

One way to resolve this is not to use Jupyter notebooks - just write a normal .py file and run it via command-line.

Or try use what's suggested here: [Jupyter notebook never finishes processing using multiprocessing (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313732/jupyter-notebook-never-finishes-processing-using-multiprocessing-python-3).

Answer (score 1):

At least in my case putting the code that creates the DataLoader in a separate python file solves the problem. A simple Wrapper is enough.

For example, create DataLoader in dataloader_wrapper.py:

```py
class DataloaderWrapper:
    def __init__(self, dataset, batch_size, num_workers, shuffle):
        self.dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, num_workers=num_workers)
```

Then import the data loader_wrapper, create and call the data loader via the wrapper in Jupyter, like this:

```py
from dataloader_wrapper import DataloaderWrapper
train_loader = DataloaderWrapper(dataset=dataset, batch_size=50000, shuffle=True, num_workers=7)

for data in train_loader.dataloader:
    pass
```

This is a bit of a workaround but works for me.

Comment: In my case this doesn`t work. But for for a couple of years my workaround has been defining dataset inhereited from torch.utils.data.Dataset in a different .py file. DataLoader then works with this DataSet with num_workers > 0 when I define and instantiate in jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Since jupyter Notebook doesn't support python multiprocessing, there are two thin libraries, you should install one of them as mentioned here [1](https://github.com/mszhanyi/gemini) and [2](https://github.com/philtrade/mpify).

I prefer to solve my problem in two ways without using any external libraries:

1. By converting my file from .ipynb format to .py format  and run it in the terminal and I write my code in the main() function as follows:

   ```
   ...
   ...

   train_set = IndexedDataset(train_data, train_target, test = False)

   train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=4)

    if `__name__ ==  '__main__'`:
        for images,label in train_loader:
            print(images.shape)
   ```
2. With multiprocessing library as follows:

In `try.ipynb`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import processing as ps

...
...

train_set = IndexedDataset(train_data, train_target, test = False)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    p = mp.Pool(8)
    r = p.map(ps.getShape,train_loader) 
    print(r)
    p.close()
```

In `processing.py` file:

```
def getShape(data):
    for i in data:
        return i[0].shape
```